# Custom Array to Custom Object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to Convert this Array to object Like shown below.

```
let a = ["CBSE/X","HOS/A/A1","FOOD/S"]
```

the result should be something like :

```
{  
   CBSE : ["X"],
   HOS  : [{ A : ["A1"] }],
   FOOD : ["S"],
}
```

What I have Tried is with

```
.split("/")
```

Tried to Split each object and so something but unable to move Forward.

Comment: Can you show your entire attempt? Also, what are the constraints? Will there always only be two or three "items" in each string? Could there be more properties, or further nested objects?

Comment: Why does `CBSE` have an array, while HOS has an array of an object, which has another array inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another shot at it, iterative, basically dequeueing through the chain of children and formatting along the way:

```js
let a = ["CBSE/X","HOS/A/A1","FOOD/S"];

const munge = a => 
  a.reduce((res, e) => {
    e = e.split("/");
    let a = [];
    res[e.shift()] = a;

    while (e.length) {
      const newKey = e.shift();
      a.push(newKey);

      if (e.length) {
        a[0] = {[newKey] : []};
        a = a[0][newKey];
      }
    }
    
    return res;
  }, {})
;

console.log(munge(a));
```

Comment:  Thanks for your help. It Helped me  

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use `split` / `reduceRight` inside  `reduce`

```js
let a = ["CBSE/X","HOS/A/A1","FOOD/S"]

let r = a.reduce((a, c) => 
    Object.assign(a, 
      c.split('/') 
       .reduceRight((a, c) => a ? [{[c]: a}] : [c], null)[0]
    )
,{})


console.log(r)
```

Comment:  Thanks for your help. It Helped me a lot.   

Answer (score 0):

If your constraints are simply that which you've outlined in your question, and there will not be any objects with more than a single property, and no strings in the array will have more than one `/`, you could use `reduce`:

```js
let a = ["CBSE/X","HOS/A/A1","FOOD/S"];

var o = a.reduce((obj, str) => {
  var items = str.split("/");
  var key = items[0];
  var val = items.length > 2 ? { [items[1]] : [items[2]] } : items[1];
  obj[key] = [val];
  return obj;
  }, {});
  
console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in TypeScript that uses recursive parsing:

```
type StringParseResult = 
    [string]
    | { key: string, value: any }

const parseStr = (str: string): StringParseResult => {
    if (str.indexOf('/') === -1) {
        return [str];
    }
    const [key, ...rest] = str.split('/');
    return {key, value: parseStringArray([rest.join('/')]) }
}

const parseStringArray = (arr: string[]): any => {
    const result: any = {};
    for (const str of arr) {
        const partial = parseStr(str);
        if ('key' in partial) {
            result[partial.key] = partial.value;
        }
        else {
            return partial;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(
    parseStringArray(["CBSE/X", "HOS/A/A1", "FOOD/S"])
);
```